# MySQL listing all entries within x days of first entry

Tags: mysql, date, between, days

I have a table *orders* with the columns *id, user_id, created_on* and *paid_amount*. I'm trying to find the entries for each user_id within the first 7 days of their first order. Here's what I have so far:

`SELECT user_id, created_on, paid_amount FROM orders WHERE created_on BETWEEN min(created_on) AND DATE_ADD(MIN(created_on), INTERVAL 7 DAY) GROUP BY user_id`

I'm guessing that the problem lies in the face that the BETWEEN-command is assigned to a single value instead of the whole table? How could I fix this?

My ultimate goal is to find out the average amount spent by all users within their first 7 days, but I think I can figure out the rest of the steps myself.

Comment: Base on the history of the question (" this question has been removed." was the text of the question, modified in 2017, 5 YEARS ago) this question should be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

This will give you first 7 day records, for each user_id

```
SELECT orders.* FROM orders
INNER JOIN (
    select user_id, min(created_on) as mindt from orders group by user_id
) t
ON orders.user_id = t.user_id AND orders.created_on <= DATE_ADD(t.mindt, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
ORDER BY user_id, created_on
```

For average paid_amount for each user, in  first 7 day, use this:

```
SELECT orders.user_id, avg(paid_amount) FROM orders
INNER JOIN (
    select user_id, min(created_on) as mindt from orders group by user_id
) t
ON orders.user_id = t.user_id AND orders.created_on <= DATE_ADD(t.mindt, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
group by orders.user_id
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That is exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate it greatly!